# Using back_insert_iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, istream

I'm trying to get started with C++, and should implement the function:

```
std::istream& readResults(std::istream& is, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<Result>> insertIt)
```

The function reads lines of the form "studentId grade" from istream and should add them to a vector type using insertIt.

Result is a struct with:

```
struct Result
{
  std::string studentId;
  size_t grade;
};
```

Can you give me a hint on how to get started?

I have tried something like this:

```
std::string studentId;
size_t grade;
Result new_result;

while(is >> studentId >> grade) {
    Result new_result = {studentId, grade};
    copy(new_result, *insertIt);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What hasn't worked?

Comment: I guess, "new_result" in the above should now be an iterator for copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to implement the function

```
std::istream& readResults(
    std::istream& is,
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<Result>> insertIt)
```

What you want to do is instead implement the template function

```
template<class InsertIterator>
std::istream& readResults(std::istream& is, InsertIterator insertIt)
```

When you pass `std::back_inserter(vec)`, the template will automatically be instantiated to the right type.

The code for this function will essentially be

```
template<class InsertIterator>
std::istream& readResults(std::istream& is, InsertIterator insertIt) {
  std::string studentId;
  size_t grade;
  while (is >> studentId >> grade) {
    Result new_result = {studentId, grade};
    *(insertIt++) = new_result;
  }
}
```

`std::copy` copies from one *iterator* to another. But you're not copying from an iterator. You're inserting elements one at a time, and you do this by dereferencing the iterator, as though it's a pointer, and then incrementing it when you're done.

Comment: It seems that "insertIt = new_result" is enough

Comment: @rize: `insertIt = new_result` works because of the way that `*` and `++` are defined on insert iterators. But you could reuse my function with other types of iterators to, for example, copy data to a vector that was already sufficiently large, overwriting the data that's already in the vector, and in that case simply using `insertIt = new_result` try to write each of the data elements into the same location. So **don't** abbreviate `*(insertIt++) = new_result` to `insertIt = new_result`!

Answer (score 3):

The std::back_insert_iterator is really cumbersome to use directly. Use the template function std::back_inserter instead (it does all the template argument inference for you).

Your readResults would become something like this then:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Result>(is), std::istream_iterator<Result>(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Provided that you have overloaded operator>> for Result.

Comment: -1: When he used `back_insert_iterator`, he posted the type signature of the function he's writing, but you posted `back_inserter` when talking about a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a read function for your `Result`, i.e., something declared like this:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Result& result)
{
    // read your result here
    return in;
}
```

With this in place, the implementation of `readResult()` becomes rather straight forward:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Result>(is), std::istream_iterator<Result>(), insertIt);
```

Other than that, you just need to call your `readResult()` function with a suitable iterator.